# all over him/all over himself

Tags: word-choice

> I found him lying on the floor with ketchup all over him/himself,
> pretending to be dead.

Hi. Is "him" or "himself" correct here?

Answer (score 3):

*He* is not a subject, so *himself* doesn't work. *Him* is fine and it refers to *his body*.

Comment: He got/smeared/spread ketchup all over himself; he was lying with ketchup all over him.

Comment: This seems to be missing a bit of explanation. Why does “he” have to be a subject?

Comment: @ColleenV so we could justify the use of "himself" somehow (but *himself* wouldn't work even if *he* **was** the subject). To make it work, we would need a completely different verb (get/smear/spread, as Michael Harvey pointed out).

Comment: Yes, I already know that, but the person you are trying to help doesn’t. That explanation really belongs in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I found him lying on the floor with ketchup all over him/himself, pretending to be dead.

With this construction, we have to use the object case, *him*.

A guide on the use of reflexive pronoun is shown here.

> Reflexive pronouns for same subject and object

> We often use reflexive pronouns when the subject and the object of the verb refer to the same person or thing:

> He cut himself on the broken glass.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-reflexive-myself-themselves-etc)

To use the reflexive case, the sentence hence could be

> I found him lying on the floor *after having smeared* ketchup all over himself, pretending to be dead.